# Correct way to add centered point in text mode

Tags: formatting, text-mode

I'm trying to learn more about LaTeX formatting and I'm getting really OCD about the proper format to use in each situation. Something that I use a lot in my writing is the [middot, cdot, interpunct](https://middot.net/) or whatever you want to call it. I'm talking about this symbol ·

Right now I'm using the inline math mode

```
Methanol $\cdots$ Ethanol
```

I'm sure that is a correct way to do this using only textmode. Any idea how?

Comment: You can simply type your centred dot: `Methanol·Ethanol` . The default encoding is now utf8, so there's no problem  if you can have it from your keyboard.

Comment: I guess that works, I was looking for a way to type it faster and it seems that Windows does not have a keyboard shortcut to input it.

Comment: I personnally use a free keyboard layout which completes  Windows default, but it's adapted to the French layout. However I think the samet probably exists for all languages.

Comment: `\textperiodcentered`

Answer (score 2):

You may create your own dot.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcommand{\mydot}{\raisebox{0.5 ex}{.}\ }
\begin{document}
Methanol \mydot Ethanol
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The command to use is `\textperiodcentered`, which is available in standard LaTeX (it might require `\usepackage{textcomp}` on older distributions.

One can also use directly the Unicode character, if the keyboard allows it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Methanol\textperiodcentered Ethanol

Methanol·Ethanol

\end{document}
```

[image]

If some space around the symbol is wanted, I suggest a command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tpc}{\,\textperiodcentered\,}

\begin{document}

Methanol\tpc Ethanol

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\,` for the spacing ensures that no line break is taken at those spaces.